# JFrame Graphics2D.drawline() x-axis origin problem in Java

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, graphics, paint

I created a JFrame. And when I draw a line with x=0, y=0 starting point in the x and y axis with Graphics2D.drawline(), it does not start from the x=0 axis of the JFrame. What should I do? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5J8WG.png)

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;



public class MyGraphics extends JFrame{


MyGraphics(){
   
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setSize(500,500);
    this.setVisible(true);
    
}
public void paint(Graphics g){
    
    Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D)g;
    
    g2D.setPaint(Color.blue);
    g2D.drawLine(0, 0, 500, 500);
    g2D.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5));
}
}
```

Comment: Standard Cartesian coordinates are not used. Y zero is at the top and increases downwards. If you want standard coordinates, you have to do a  transform on the Y axis. Also, it's much better to do drawing in a dedicated ```JPanel``` . Override ```JPanel.paintComponent```

Answer (score 0):

It starts from (0,0) but it is covered by top bar of window frame.
To see this, put

```
this.setUndecorated(true);
```

as the first line in constructor. It will show a window without top bar.